# Separate boxplots for multiple violin plot

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat, ggplot2

I am using the following function from seurat package to generate multiple violon plots and I am interested in adding box plots to them but it doesn't work when I have plotted different data at once.
Is there a way to solve it ?

For example, this works:

```
library(Seurat)
VlnPlot(object = pbmc_small, features.plot = 'PC1') +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

But this will simply lead into an empty box on top of my plots:

```
VlnPlot(object = pbmc_small, features.plot = c('PC1', 'PC2')) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the violin plots are combined using `cowplot::plot_grid` before being returned by VlnPlot. You can prevent the plots from being combined by setting `combine=FALSE`, then modify each one by adding a boxplot, then combine the modified plots using `Seurat::CombinePlots`.

However, the combine argument is currently broken in VlnPlot. I have pushed a fix but it's not on the public branch yet. VlnPlot is just a wrapper around ExIPlot (expression by identity plot) in Seurat v3 so right now this will work:

```
library(Seurat)
library(ggplot2)

plots <- ExIPlot(object = pbmc_small,
                 features = c('PC1', 'PC2'),
                 pt.size = 1, 
                 combine = FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(plots)) {
  plots[[i]] <- plots[[i]] + geom_boxplot() + theme(legend.position = 'none')
}
CombinePlots(plots)
```

[image: VlnPlot]

Note this answer is for Seurat v3

Answer (score 2):

The `vioplot` package comes built in with boxplots. You can download it from CRAN or there are more features (including formula input and separate colours) in the development version on GitHub: https://github.com/TomKellyGenetics/vioplot

```
devtools::install_github(“TomKellyGenetics/vioplot”)
library(“vioplot”)
vioplot(pbmc_small@dr@pca[,1]~pbmc_small@meta.data$ident)
```

To plot several PCs:

```
library(“RColorBrewer”)
colours <- brewer.pal(length(unique(pbmc_small@meta.data$ident)), “Set3”)
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
vioplot(pbmc_small@dr@pca[,1]~pbmc_small@meta.data$ident, main = “PC1”, xlab = “Identity”, col = colours)
vioplot(pbmc_small@dr@pca[,2]~pbmc_small@meta.data$ident , main = “PC2”, xlab = “Identity”, col = colours)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: You can add points to these with jitter: `plot(pbmc_small@dr@pca[,1]~jitter(pbmc_small@meta.data$ident, 0.5), add = TRUE)`

Comment: This version is now support on CRAN